# What laptop keyboards are easy to disassemble and clean?

Tags: keyboard, hardware-rec, laptop-repair, cleaning

I often use my laptop on construction jobsites or in very dirt-filled situations. Over time, the keyboard gets dusty, greasy, etc. Pieces of detritus fall down underneath the keys, and come to interfere with their action over time. We're talking about a lot of dirt: people have dumped sawdust on it, accidentally spilled a bag of grout over it...you name it, and that's without the average high-mess daily use I put it through.

I personally really dislike latex or similar laptop keyboard covers. So my question is:

**What models of laptop or laptop keyboard are very easy to disassemble and thoroughly clean?**

**What I've tried/considered:**
I'm reasonably technical and have plenty of time in which to perform said cleaning, but after taking out and cleaning the keyboard on a 2009 unibody MacBook Pro (so many tiny screws), I'm hoping for something that is easier to disassemble/access/clean.

Hardware specifications and platform are irrelevant, since I do most of my work in a browser anyway.

I've looked into the ToughBook line, but they seem to simply isolate the keyboard from the rest of the laptop (reducing risk from a liquid spill), but aren't particularly cleanable.

Comment: This is – in essence – a shopping recommendation question, and answers will quickly become outdated, apart from the fact that there is an infinite amount of possible answers.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't really think of that aspect of it. Was more hoping for design recommendations but your point is valid. Feel free to delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend the Lenovo Thinkpad T series.  We have dozens of them at work and we have standardized on them because of their easy to swap parts.  You can take out the keyboard with about 2 screws and it just pops off.  The keys also easily pop off (but only when you want), and are easy to clean, change, etc.

It was built to be taken apart, and upgraded or cleaned and yet it's tough enough for the road warriors and fast enough for the engineers.

Good luck in your search, definitely check out the Thinkpad series.